# How to clear wxpython frame content when dragging a panel?

Tags: python, wxpython, refresh, panel

I have 3 panels and I want to make drags on them.
The problem is that when I do a drag on one this happens:
[http://img41.yfrog.com/img41/9043/soundlog.png http://img41.yfrog.com/img41/9043/soundlog.png](http://img41.yfrog.com/img41/9043/soundlog.png)

How can I refresh the frame to happear its color when the panel is no longer there?

This is the code that I have to make the drag:

```
def onMouseMove(self, event):
    (self.pointWidth, self.pointHeight) = event.GetPosition()
    (self.width, self.height) = self.GetSizeTuple()
    if (self.pointWidth>100 and self.pointWidth<(self.width-100) and self.pointHeight < 15) or self.parent.dragging:
        self.SetCursor(wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_SIZING))

        """implement dragging"""
        if not event.Dragging():
            self.w = 0
            self.h = 0
            return
        self.CaptureMouse()
        if self.w == 0 and self.h == 0:
            (self.w, self.h) = event.GetPosition()
        else:
            (posw, posh) = event.GetPosition()
            displacement = self.h - posh
            self.SetPosition( self.GetPosition() - (0, displacement))
    else:
        self.SetCursor(wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_ARROW))

def onDraggingDown(self, event):
    if self.pointWidth>100 and self.pointWidth<(self.width-100) and self.pointHeight < 15:
        self.parent.dragging = 1
        self.SetCursor(wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_ARROW))
        self.SetBackgroundColour('BLUE')
        self.parent.SetTransparent(220)
        self.Refresh()

def onDraggingUp(self, event):
    self.parent.dragging = 0
    self.parent.SetTransparent(255)
    self.SetCursor(wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_ARROW))
```

and this are the binds for this events:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.onMouseMove)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.onDraggingDown)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.onDraggingUp)
```

With this, if I click on the top of the panel, and move down or up, the panel position changes (I drag the panel) to the position of the mouse.

Comment: what do you mean by "make drags on them" ? can you put some self contained sample code which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I put the code, do you understand it now?

Comment: Can you put some code which I can just run without copy paste, so i can see problem first-hand and fix it.

Comment: You can download it here (soz for the wait):
http://www.2shared.com/file/12230037/b5ee8e79/SoundLog.html

Execute SoundLog :) asnd try it. Now, can you answer me? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refresh the parent on every repositioning of `self`, you could add

```
self.parent.Refresh()
```

right after your existing call to `self.SetPosition` in your `def onMouseMove` method. Right now you're refreshing the frame only in the `def onDraggingDown` method, i.e., the first time the mouse left button is clicked and held down, not every time the mouse is moved while said button is held down (i.e., the "dragging" action itself).

I was unable to download your code for testing purposes, due to the rather "spammy peculiar" site you chose to upload it to -- the site keeps bombarding me with ads, no clear way for me to just do the download, occasionally complaining that it doesn't support my machine (I use a Mac and Google Chrome, the site at some spots insists on Windows with IE or Firefox...), etc etc. I'm sure you can find other sites, more usable than that one, for people who are trying to help you out!-)

Comment: I've allready tested self.parent.Refresh() before I made this question :(